# How best to insert a stream of messages from a C app into RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a C-based app which is collecting measurement streams which I want to dump in to RethinkDB. There is no need for any queries, just creating a table and inserting data. Is anybody aware of such as simple library?

There is the [AtnNn/librethinkdbxx](https://github.com/AtnNn/librethinkdbxx) driver which I most likely could wrap easily, but it has no documentation and C++ and I don't get along well :)

Answer (score 1):

RethinkDB protocol isn't that hard to write your own driver, like a simple C driver with write command support only

However, I propose that you abstract it and using a simple HTTP server to write into RethinkDB. You can do this with NodeJS in under 100 lines of code easily since you only need to write.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but I have a lot of data and the incoming data stream is binary encoded which I don't really want to re-code in nodeJS - beside most likely running into performance issues